# How to prove: $GH\cdot DJ=GD\cdot JH$

Tags: geometry

In any $\Delta ABC$, and the incenters of the triangle $ABC$ is $I$, and let $D$, $E$, and $ F$ be the points on $BC$, $AC$, $AB$, respectively, and the point $M$ is on $AD$, such that $AD$, $BM$, $CM$ and $\bigodot I$ meet $H$, $G$, $J$, respectively.

> show that:
>   $$GH\cdot DJ=GD\cdot JH$$

[image]

My try: let $AB=c,BC=a,AC=b$, then
$$\dfrac{AB}{AC}=\dfrac{BD}{DC}\Longrightarrow BD=\dfrac{ac}{b+c},DC=\dfrac{ab}{b+c} $$

and $$AD^2=AB\cdot AC-BD\cdot DC=bc-\dfrac{a^2bc}{(b+c)^2}\Longrightarrow AD=\dfrac{\sqrt{bc(b^2+c^2-a^2+2bc)}}{b+c}$$

let $AM=kAD$,
so use http://zh-cn.enc.tfode.com/%E6%96%AF%E5%8F%B0%E6%B2%83%E7%89%B9%E5%AE%9A%E7%90%86

we  have
$$BM\cdot AD^2+DM\cdot AB^2=(BM+DM)\cdot AM^2+BM\cdot DM(BM+DM)$$
 then I can't work, so I think this problem have other nice methods. Thank you.

Comment: Off topic, but how did you draw this?